# Google API - OAuth 2.0 - trying to get AccessToken using curl

Tags: curl, google-api, google-oauth, omniauth-google-oauth2

Trying to get AccessToken using curl but getting error as
"https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token: No such file or directory"
Can someone help what i am doing wrong?

Mainly, am wondering if I am setting up the client secret correctly, though I'm quite unsure, would really appreciate some guidance.

(have redacted some part by *)

```
curl \
—request POST \
--data ”code=4/***********************3Uzp--0jT4uNN******rSWSRkHw8&client_id=***************************.apps.googleusercontent.com&client_secret=**********&redirect_uri=https://localhost&grant_type=authorization_code” \https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the code i use.

```
# Client id from Google Developer console
# Client Secret from Google Developer console
# Scope this is a space seprated list of the scopes of access you are requesting.

# Authorization link.  Place this in a browser and copy the code that is returned after you accept the scopes.
https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?client_id=[Application Client Id]&redirect_uri=urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob&scope=[Scopes]&response_type=code

# Exchange Authorization code for an access token and a refresh token.

curl \
--request POST \
--data "code=[Authentcation code from authorization link]&client_id=[Application Client Id]&client_secret=[Application Client Secret]&redirect_uri=urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob&grant_type=authorization_code" \
https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token

# Exchange a refresh token for a new access token.
curl \
--request POST \
--data 'client_id=[Application Client Id]&client_secret=[Application Client Secret]&refresh_token=[Refresh token granted by second step]&grant_type=refresh_token' \
https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token
```

Code ripped from one of my gists [GoogleAuthenticationCurl.sh](https://gist.github.com/LindaLawton/cff75182aac5fa42930a09f58b63a309)

## update

after the removal of OOB `urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob`  should be changed to `http://127.0.0.1` look in the url bar the code will be there but you will see a 404 error on the page itself.

Comment: Thank-you, i got the access token.

Comment: Your ans was correct, exactly what i was looking for,thank-you once again.

Comment: This looks like exactly what I have been looking for also. My only problem is the Authorization link. It does not seem to be working anymore. Any updates for getting this?

Comment: For updated endpoints check the [discovery doc](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/openid-connect#discovery)

Comment: @LindaLawton-DaImTo , how to get the Code please

Comment: What code that should be the code you need